# Convert jpg/pdf to text/excel

Tags: scala

I have a pdf which contain table with some data (waste disposal schedule). Unfortunatelly this table is image.
Is there any way to convert that table to some program readable data sequence?
Example of that kind of file: [schedule](https://eko-region.pl/assets/schedulers/Pabianice_Gmina/29afea9f01/Pabianice-Gmina-7.pdf)

I tried for research some online tools but none of them convert this table correctly.

Comment: There are many [resources online](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala+ocr+libraries) discussing OCR tools and libraries in scala. Unfortunately, such discussions are off-topic on this site, but you can find some advise on reddit quora or slant (some discussions referenced in the link above). Or explore [tesseract](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ocr-tesseract), which may just be what you want.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.